# Cannot allocate memory while installing nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, centos7

I'm trying to install nodejs on centos 7. however, it has error message as below:

```
   Error downloading packages:
 libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
 1:libuv-1.10.2-1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.9.4.2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
 1:nodejs-6.9.4-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Please help how to fix it? Thanks

=========================
Thank you for answer. I found the php-fpm are eating up the ram thoug I haven't hit any web page from the front end. Please help how to fix. Thanks.

```
   12.9648 MB              php-fpm:
   13.5508 MB              /usr/local/sa/agent/plugins/sap1005
   18.1406 MB              /usr/local/sa/agent/secu-tcs-agent
   43.3594 MB              php-fpm:
   45.3281 MB              php-fpm:
   45.3281 MB              php-fpm:
   45.332 MB               php-fpm:
   45.3398 MB              php-fpm:
   45.3477 MB              php-fpm:
   45.6992 MB              php-fpm:
   45.7031 MB              php-fpm:
```

Comment: Possibly you don't have enough RAM available. You can try stopping other applications while you install the required package.

Comment: Thank  you for answer. I found there're few php-fpm running behind. I restart php-fpm. however, no. of php-fpm are increased up to 9 and each took around 45mb ram though i haven't hit any web page from the front end.